# How to read database from chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am working on a dictionary extension where I will get the word and meaning. Here is the expected output.

1. User selects the text from DOM.
2. extension should show the meaning of the word in a pop-up like a google dictionary.
   I am not using any API instead I wanted to look for words from an SQL database(dictionarydb.sqlite 5.8mb).

**Question: is it possible to add a pre-build database within the extension? if so how can we load and search for a word?**
Here is the snippet of content.js

```
//get the selected word from the document and send it to the background js
document.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
  if (window.getSelection().toString().length) {
    let exactText = window.getSelection().toString();
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      selectedText: exactText,
    });
  }
});

//get the word meaning from background js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
  if (msg.from == "background") {
    var wordMeaning = msg.meaning;
    alert("Meaning: " + wordMeaning);
  }
});
```

In background.js,

```
//get selected word from content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender) {
  var text = request.selectedText;
  var textMeaning;
/*
textMeaning = get Meaning from dictionary
*/
 //send word meaning to content.js
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, {
    from: "background",
    meaning: textMeaning,
  });

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can include a json file, read it in chrome.runtime.onInstalled into chrome.storage.local or IndexedDB.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm so converting 5MB of SQL database to JSON and inserting it in indexedDb is a good approach? or is there any other way?

Comment: Yeah, there's no API to read sqlite file directly, so you would have to use a js library to parse the file manually, which arguably would be [much] slower than reading json.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I just converted database to json and now json is around 12 MB, is it fine for inserting,querying and reading data from indexedDB? Will it effect performance or memory issue? What is the limit size for indexDB, localstorage? which one should I go?

Comment: There's no limit. I need to see a sample of the db to comment further. See also the documentation for more info.